# MongoDB - objects? Why do I need _id in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is an example from MongoDB tutorial (here it collection [ZIP Code db](http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json?_ga=1.182301729.761139424.1432155625):

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: "$state", totalPop: { $sum: "$pop" } } },
   { $match: { totalPop: { $gte: 10*1000*1000 } } }
] )
```

if I replace `_id` with something else like word `Test`, I will get error message:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: the group aggregate field 'Test' must be defined as an expression inside an object",
"code" : 15951,
"ok" : 0
```

Could anybody help me understand why I need `_id` in my command? I thought MongoDB assigns IDs automatically, if used does not provide it.

Answer (score 9):

The `_id` field is mandatory, but you can set it to `null` if you do *not* wish to aggregate with respect to a key, or keys. Not utilising it would result in a single aggregate value over the fields. It is thus acting a 'reserved word' in this context, indicating what the resulting 'identifier'/key is for each group.

In your case, grouping by `_id: "$state"` would result in `n` aggregate results of `totalPop`, provided there there are `n` distinct values for `state` (akin to `SELECT SUM() FROM table GROUP BY state`). Whereas,

```
$group : {_id : null, totalPop: { $sum: "$pop" }}}
```

would provide a single result for `totalPop` (akin to `SELECT SUM() FROM table`).

This behaviour is well described in the group operator [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Answer (score 8):

In a `$group` stage, `_id` is used to designate the group condition. You obviously need it.

If you're familiar with the SQL world, think of it as the `GROUP BY` clause.

---

<sub>Please note, in that context too, `_id` is really an unique identifier in the generated collection, as by definition `$group` cannot produce two documents having the same value for that field.</sub>

Comment: In SQL I have group by and I have field to group by $state, _id does not look like any SQL analog.

Answer (score 6):

We're going to understand the `_id` field within the `$group` stage & look at some best practices for constructing `_id`s in group aggregation stages. Let's look at this query:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: {
      $gte: 2010
    }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: {
      founded_year: "$founded_year"
    },
    companies: {
      $push: "$name"
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    "_id.founded_year": 1
  }
}]).pretty()
```

[image: MongoDB $group with document approach]

One thing which might not be clear to us is why the `_id` field is constructed this "document" way?  We could have done it this way as well:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: {
      $gte: 2010
    }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$founded_year",
    companies: {
      $push: "$name"
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    "_id": 1
  }
}]).pretty()
```

[image: MongoDB $group without document approach]

We don't do it this way, because in these output documents - it's not explicit what exactly this number means. So, we actually don't know. And in some cases, that means there maybe confusion in interpreting these documents. So, another case maybe to group an `_id` document with multiple fields:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: {
      $gte: 2010
    }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: {
      founded_year: "$founded_year",
      category_code: "$category_code"
    },
    companies: {
      $push: "$name"
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    "_id.founded_year": 1
  }
}]).pretty()
```

[image: group an _id document with multiple fields in MongoDB]

`$push` simply pushes the elements to generating arrays. Often, it might be required to group on promoted fields to upper level:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      ipo_year: "$ipo.pub_year"
    },
    companies: {
      $push: "$name"
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    "_id.ipo_year": 1
  }
}]).pretty()
```

[image: group on promoted fields to upper level in MongoDB]

It's also perfect to have an expression that resolves to a document as a `_id` key.

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    "relationships.person": {
      $ne: null
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    relationships: 1,
    _id: 0
  }
}, {
  $unwind: "$relationships"
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: "$relationships.person",
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    count: -1
  }
}])
```

[image: It's also perfect to have an expression that resolves to a document as a _id key in MongoDB]